# What is the best practice in MVVM with knockout.js: using domain classes, DTO or custom models for each form

Tags: asp.net-mvc, mvvm, knockout.js, dto

I am making an MVVM website using knockout.js and ASP.MVC.

Everything here seems pretty straightforward, until I faced complex web forms.
I have a set of DTO classes  representing my domain model objects.

The form, that I am creating, is quite complex and does not reflect DTOs from my domain.
So I have 2 options here:

1. Manually create a custom model class representing my form's data. Create REST methods which return/accept this class and make viewmodel use this class in order to populate/collect data from the form.
2. Use clear REST methods which return/accept only domain DTOs. Use JavaScript in order to call REST methods, get DTOs, and create a complex object for form data-binding in JavaScript.

Comment: You should not modify model layer to comply with view's expectations. That's why you chose to use MVVM to begin with.

Answer (score 3):

Your ViewModel is a *'model of your view'*, so its interface should closely reflect the client UI. This means that the view model should adapt your DTOs in order to present this interface.

Comment: No , it isn't. ViewModel is a structure, which transforms data from model layer into format, that can be handled by view.

Comment: Conceptually it is useful to think of the view model as a 'model of a view', hence the way I italicized this. It is not a strict definition, but a useful guide. Google this phrase and you will see that it is quite commonly used to describe a view model.

Comment: It is also common to presume that ActiveRecord is Model. That does not make it true. And i disagree which whole post, not just the italicized part.